# How can i stock a website address in a var

Tags: jquery

I have my website adress which is like this when i'm in the back office :

http://myadress.com/admin/mypage.php

http://myadress.com/admin/mypage2.php

etc...

I want to get in Jquery only http://myadress.com/, i don't want to have admin/ or admin/mypage.php.

What is the solution ?

I want to have something like this :

```
 var file = $(".input_file").val();
   var adress = http://myadress.com/;
   $.ajax({
  url: ''+adress+'/img/'+file+'',
  success: function(data){
    alert('exists');
  },
  error: function(data){
    alert(file);
  },
})
```

Comment: Wrap it in quotes, and you're all set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can fetch information information about the current location of the document using [**Window.location**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.location) object

Use

```
var adress = window.location.origin;
```

if you have hard-code url. use quotes

```
var adress = 'http://myadress.com/';
```

You can also use

```
var address = window.location.protocol + '//' + window.location.hostname;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `window.location.origin`, which will give you just the origin without the path names.:

```
var address = window.location.origin;
```

Answer (score 0):

window.location.origin; will return in a string. If you need to build your own, try putting quotes around the string (as all quotes need to be surrounded by single or double quotes in any language.

Answer (score 0):

Store the address and use it as a string, like this:

```
var file = $(".input_file").val();
var address = "http://myaddress.com/";
$.ajax({
  url: address + "img/" + file,
  success: function(data){
    // exists
  },
  error: function(data){
    // doesn't exist
  }
});
```

But be aware, if the domain doesn't match the domain your code is running on, you'll run into [same-origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) restrictions. Basically, a site running on **www.example.com** can only make requests to other pages at **www.example.com**, and *not* **www.anothersite.com** or even **somethingelse.example.com**. Those requests will fail.